# How to include url filter parameters in mongoose get call

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, restify

I've coded a get call for mongoose+restify which successfully returns a set of values under a variable (e.g. all cheese type names) via req.params, but I'm looking to add the filter functionality i.e. Cheese?type=blue. I understand these url parameters can be accessed via req.query, but I'm not sure how to pass them via the cheese.find function.

If the standard case is:

cheese = cheese.find({"name": req.params.name})

how should I include req.query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple, you only need to learn MongoDB in using AND.

For your case, you can use the example below:

If the type is in the **same collection**, you can use the example below.

```
const params = req.params;
const query = req.query;

cheese = cheese.find({ $and: [ params, query ]})
```

If the type is in a **different collection**, then you can try to learn aggregation in MongoDB.

That's All.

I hope it's can help you.